# Powershell, Export xls file

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-excel

I would like to export the results to a xls file (not to a csv file)
Is there any easy way to export the results to the Excel file format?

```
Get-EventLog System -newest 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2009/02/02/xml-part-2-write-add-and-change-xml-data.aspx

look at the middle bottom.